# Calling the column in call method in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ddl

Why is not working for executing the alter table in stored procedure? I tried everything but nothing is working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE change_datatypes(columnname VARCHAR(255), datatype VARCHAR(255))
language plpgsql
as $$

BEGIN

    EXECUTE
    ALTER TABLE public.Sales_2019 ALTER COLUMN columnname TYPE datatype USING columnname :: datatype;
END $$;

CALL change_datatypes(Sales_2019.orderid, 'INTEGER') FROM Sales_2019;
```

UPDATED

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE change_datatypes(column_name VARCHAR(255), datatype VARCHAR(255))
language plpgsql
as $$

BEGIN

    EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE Sales_2019 ALTER COLUMN' 
            || quote_ident(column_name) 
            ||'TYPE' || quote_literal(datatype) || 'USING '
            ||quote_ident(column_name) || '::' 
            ||quote_literal(datatype));
END $$;

CALL change_datatypes(OrderID, INTEGER);
```

Comment: You need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and since you are using DDL you cannot use `format` and parameters. You will need to build the query and use `quote_ident`.

Comment: Am I still gonna use the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, you just need to bring it inline with the examples shown at the linked docs.

Comment: How will I call the call method? ```ERROR:  column "orderid" does not exist```

Comment: I am trying to change the datatype that's why I create column_name and datatype as my parameters

Comment: You need to add the updated code to your question.

Comment: That should be `CALL change_datatypes('OrderID', 'INTEGER');` as the arguments are `varchar`,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249816/discussion-between-chris-and-adrian-klaver).